# How to create cloud database for WPF application in C# project

Tags: c#

I'm doing a c# project using WPF application.I need to create a cloud database and to connect with my project but i was enable to find any videos or tutorial in Google and Youtube. How can i do this ?

for now I have created database from SQL Server and connected it to c# project.

I need the steps and instructions to do this including code.

Comment: Asking about how to make something or recommendations are out of scope in the StackOverflow community. I think that your problem is how to use a remote DB in C#, you should investigate about Entity Framework or ADO.NET as startint point

Comment: I have already created a database using SQL Server and connected it to visual basic using ADO.NET .I want to know ,how to cloud my database and to connect it

Comment: Azure, AWS and Google Cloud all have multiple solutions for databases. If you were to use Azure SQL your code would require nothing more than a connection string update. However, it is not cheap unless you can get away with a very small level of service.